# How to get line number causing an exception (other than TemplateSyntaxError) in Jinja2 template?

Tags: python, jinja2

When a template contains a syntax error, Jinja throws a TemplateSyntaxError which has a `lineno` attribute containing the template line number where the error occurred.

How can I get the line number when an error occurs which is not a syntax error?  For example, the following tag:

```
{{ len(SettlementDate)+1 }}
```

causes Jinja to throw a TypeError if SettlementDate is not something list-like.  How can I then find out where this error occurred, for reporting to the user?  For my use case, sanitizing the context variables in advance is not an option.

Answer (score 3):

jinja2 is modifying system traceback, so you may find this function useful (note - it relies on `<template>` filename, which will differ if you use FileSystemLoader - you should implement better variant in that case):

```py
from jinja2 import TemplateError
from sys import exc_info


def jinja2_template_error_lineno():
    type, value, tb = exc_info()
    if not issubclass(type, TemplateError):
        return None
    if hasattr(value, 'lineno'):
        # in case of TemplateSyntaxError
        return value.lineno
    while tb:
        if tb.tb_frame.f_code.co_filename == '<template>':
            return tb.tb_lineno
        tb = tb.tb_next
```

Comment: This is a great answer. Note however that if the error is triggered by a child template included, the <template> traceback will only point to the include statement in the top-most template. You can however continue to follow the tb.tb_next and the tb_frame will actually be the path of the included templates. We can then implement a full traceback of an exception.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran across this problem.  Unfortunately it seems to be a common problem with no solution.  Just to make the research easier for the next character who comes along, here are some related references:

https://github.com/saltstack/salt/issues/21298
https://github.com/saltstack/salt/issues/28345

Yes, those references are related to saltstack specifically but the underlying problem in jinja is there.

I built a workaround in my specific use-case:

```
  try:
    output = env.get_template(
        "envoy.{}.yaml".format(args.type.lower())
    ).render(**context)
    print("Template is hydrated")
  except Exception as e:
    print(
        """
            Error Generating Template!
            --------------------------
            Error:    {}
            Template: {}

            An error occurred hydrating the template with the context
            parameters.  The error exists in either the context or the
            template but has nothing to do with the YAML formatting of
            the template at this time.

        """.format(e,args.template)
    )
    if args.debug:
        print(output)
    else:
        print("\nTry running with --debug for more info.")
    sys.exit(1)
```

Disclaimer: Using --debug in my actual solution pukes an ugly stacktrace that increases the learning curve for a user.  You have to read that stacktrace to find the line specific to the template, e.g. this one:

File "/Users/scaldwell/git//src/serviceProxy/.yaml", line 4, in template
    {% from "includes/listener.payload.noop.yaml" import payload_listener_noop with context %}

This should be cleaner output....  Maybe I will make fixing this a weekend project or Atlassian ShipIt Project some day.  Until then, this is what JINJA seems to offer.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/20338783)

Comment: There is a work-around in code here as well.  I would think that this should be sufficient.

Comment: What is `args`?

Answer (score 0):

Building on top of Victor's answer, I made this function that prints the full traceback through the templates when working with includes.

```py
# Return pretty traceback string of Jinja2 render
tb_frame_re = re.compile(r"<frame at 0x[a-z0-9]*, file '(.*)', line (\d+), (?:code top-level template code|code template)>")
def jinja2_render_traceback(src_path)
  traceback_print = ""
  # Get traceback objects
  typ, value, tb = exc_info()
  # Iterate over nested traceback frames
  while tb:
    # Parse traceback frame string
    tb_frame_str = str(tb.tb_frame)
    tb_frame_match = tb_frame_re.match(tb_frame_str)
    tb_frame_istemplate = False
    # Identify frames corresponding to Jinja2 templates
    if tb.tb_frame.f_code.co_filename == '<template>':
      # Top-most template
      tb_src_path = src_path
      tb_lineno = tb.tb_lineno
      tb_frame_istemplate = True
    elif tb_frame_match:
      # nested child templates
      tb_src_path = tb_frame_match.group(1)
      tb_lineno = tb_frame_match.group(2)
      tb_frame_istemplate = True
    # Factorized string formatting
    if tb_frame_istemplate:
      traceback_print += f"  Template '{tb_src_path}', line {tb_lineno}\n"
      # Fetch the line raising the exception
      with open(tb_src_path,'r') as tb_src_file:
        for lineno,line in enumerate(tb_src_file):
          if lineno == int(tb_lineno)-1:
            traceback_print += "    "+line.strip()+"\n"
            break
    tb = tb.tb_next
  # Strip the final line jump
  return traceback_print[:-1]
```

Note that `src_path` is the path to the top-most template on which jinja2 render is called.

Example of the traceback for an error with nested includes :

```
  Template '/data/scratch/company/louis.duret-robert/project/src/main.j2', line 11
    {% include 'targets/' ~ target.compiler ~ '/main.j2' with context %}
  Template '/data/scratch/company/louis.duret-robert/project/src/targets/supplier/main.j2', line 18
    {% include 'tool.spec.j2' with context %}
  Template '/data/scratch/company/louis.duret-robert/project/src/targets/supplier/tool.spec.j2', line 2
    # Compiler : {{ compiler.type }}
```

Answer (score -3):

I think that in jinja the built-in function is `length()` instead of `len()`.

http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#length

Comment: I have manually added the len function to the `globals` dictionary in the Jinja2 environment.  `length` / `count` are filters not functions and I need a function in my use case.